Are Arena Tournaments (like Chess.com) type events used for OTB chess?
Arena Tournaments seems a pratical system that pair people based on playing ability, allowing more games in a day for players that use less time and can cope with players joining/leaving at any point of the tournament.
But I have not come across them as a OTB format.
https://lichess.org/tournament/help
https://support.chess.com/en/articles/8562889-what-are-arena-tournaments

The Arena format does not seem common for over the board tournaments in the U.S. Through several years of playing, I've only seen one. That was at a chess festival celebrating the re-opening of a chess center (after a relocation). That  arena tournament was unrated, and was limited to school age kids, many of whom had never played a tournament.

Many chess clubs have internal arena tournaments for selecting a team to represent them. These usually aren't too formal, with players with the same number of wins being paired on the spot as soon as they are free from their game, at the discretion of the coach. Selections to the team are done based on the number of wins, where there is an incentive to win faster so you can play more games.
About official FIDE tournaments, I have yet to see any in the arena format.

"Many chess clubs" -- I've never heard of this and I've seen quite some chess clubs, where is this method common?

Many, not most of them. At least here in India, and the two that I have been in.
